# Importing database and app server configurations from ML 8 to ML10 in Marklogic

Tags: configuration, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-10

We have the app related app server and database configurations exported from ML8 environment using Configuration Manager App as a package zip.The configuration xmls in the zip have the root element starting with `<package-XXX>`.E.g. `<package-database>`.

We are in need to import this into a new ML10 environment.But here the Configuration Manager UI is deprecated.How could we import this zip configurations into ML 10 and apply it using `cma:apply-config` API?

I tried passing a configuration xml of an app sever from the zip to the `cma:apply-config` function.It is returning empty sequence but the resource is not getting created in ML10. Please let me know the best approach to do this.

Comment: https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/alternatives-to-configuration-manager

Comment: @MichaelGardner Viewed this article already and tried cma API.But this cma module is not available in ML8 ,so not able to get the configurations in the required format to use this API